# Arbitrary element in array (the value) to a key that is an array

Tags: php, cakephp

So, I have an array that looks like this:

```
$grades =
Array(

    [0] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 0 [name] => Kindegarten ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => First ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Second ) ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Third ) ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Fourth ) ) 
    [5] => Array ( [Grade] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Fifth ) ) 

    )//End array
```

I am wondering is there a way to arbitrarily way to pick a key (the first 0-5)? CakePHP returns the items in my table like this and I don't understand how I can conform the to the printing of Form helper with the options.

```
echo $this->Form->input('grade_selection', 
        array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => array($grades[?]['Grade']['id'] => $grades[?]['Grade']['name'])));
```

The ? being how to get it to change in the option so I can get each of the items in the array?

```
class GradesController extends AppController {
    public function index(){
        //Gets all the rows in the grade table and stores it into a variable called grade. 
        //$grades = $this->Grade->find('all'); 
        $grades = $this->Grade->getGrades();

        //Returns the $grades variable when it is requested. 
        if($this->request->is('requested')){
            return $grades;
        }

        //Sends the $grades variable to the view file. The string 'grades' is the name of the variable that the Grades View file will have the same setup as the $grades.
        $this->set('grades', $grades);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering is there a way to arbitrarily way to pick a key (the first 0-5)?

Yes, php, not CakePHP

```
$keys = array_keys($grades);
$foo = $keys[rand(0, count($keys) - 1)]
```

Now, I don't think that's what you need. I see you are using a radio button, what do you want to display in the radio button(s)?

EDIT

Assuming this data come from a Model named "Grade", you would do this in your crontroller

```
$grades = $this->Grade->find('list');
$this->set(compact('grades'));
```

Then, in your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('grade_selection', array('options' => $grades));
```

Comment: I want to display the grade name next to the radio button. I want the value to be the id. So for example I want the radio button Kindergarten and its value to be 0 (the id). Example: <input type='radio' value='0'>Kindergarten

Comment: paste your controller code (I want to see where $grades come from)

Comment: Updated the main question with the controller code. The $this->Grade->getGrades(); basically does what the commented line above it says.

Comment: Fantastic. So last question, what is the compact function do? Is it just the normal PHP one?

Comment: Yes, this "compact" is the one from PHP. It is basically a shortcut to write less :)

So, instead of writing

    $this->set('grades', $grades)

You just write

   $this->set(compact('grades'))

Comment: Ah, gotcha. One more question (lol), what is the find('list') portion?

Comment: Model::find('list') will do a regular find in your table and will format the result array for the exact purpose you were looking for, that is, 'id' => 'name'. [Here is the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)